# I need to animate this jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, onmouseover

How would I go about animating the following javascript code?

```
$('img').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).attr({
        src: $(this).attr('data-other-src'), 'data-other-src': $(this).attr('src'),
        'style': $(this).attr('data-other-style'), 'data-other-style': $(this).attr('style')
    });
});
```

what it does it switches one image for another and it changes the style, I need make it fade in/out on mouseenter/mouseleave

Thanks for your help.

Louis

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are doing it wrongly,Instead you can have two elements and hide and show them accordingly, and $.toggle() method itself comes with animation properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not sure how to do that with my code, I newbie with jquery